# Android detect which hardware key pressed

Tags: adb, keyboard

Is there a utility which detects which hardware key was pressed?

I can only find resources for simulating key presses but not for detecting them.

Something similar to `xev` on Linux.

Comment: *'getevent -il'* get device with three event names *KEY_VOLUMEDOWN + KEY_VOLUMEUP + KEY_POWER* then listen with *'getevent -lc4 /dev/input/event0'* or with wrapper shell function [GetKeyEvent](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=78690858&postcount=354)

Comment: @alecxs That works. Please make that an answer.